# How do I find out which files were used in insmod in Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm working on a script which runs on various types of CentOS/Redhat servers where it needs to find out which files were loaded into the kernel. Running lsmod provides me with the name of the module (which may be set using -o in the call to insmod) but not the file that was loaded.

Is there anyway to find out which files were loaded into the kernel as modules? Preferably, with the ability to cross reference with the name as it appears in lsmod?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is not recorded anywhere, as far as I know. Even if it was, the information might not be accurate if the file was moved or removed in the meantime (which would explain why no one implemented such a feature).

Given a module name `foo`, `modprobe -l foo` shows what file would now be loaded if the module `foo` was requested. But if `modprobe -o bar` was used to load a module, the default module name is not recorded, only `bar`.

Comment: I come from a Windows background - where such files are normally easy to identify and usually locked for access (moving, renaming, etc.). Does the kernel hold any file descriptors to the files it loaded (after loading them)? Or maybe logs by default which files were loaded and under what names?

Comment: @Yon: The kernel itself never opens a file. `insmod` and `modprobe` work by loading the code from the `.ko` file into memory and passing that in-memory copy to the kernel. Then the kernel keeps its own copy of the code. If you need this information, you'll need to keep your own logs (and make sure you don't delete or move the module files, for example by doing a kernel upgrade). Note that this is a general philosophy in the unix world: renaming or removing files is supposed to always work, and not cause trouble unless something later tries to open the file.

Comment: Thank you for this. We'll find another solution. In accordance with this site's regulations, is an answer which says "that's not possible" considered to be a good answer to a question (if it's a true answer?

Comment: @Yon: I can hardly answer this since I'm an interested party. Check the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) regarding accepted answers, and if you still can't decide, look on [meta](http://meta.superuser.com/) and [SO meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) or ask on [meta](http://meta.superuser.com/).

Comment: Well, according to the FAQ it should be the "most helpful" answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing a bit and found the following commands.

```
$ lsmod | cut -d " " -f 1
```

will output a list of loaded modules.

```
$ modinfo modulename -n
```

will output the filename of the module.

```
$ list=`lsmod | cut -d " " -f 1`; echo "$list" | while read line; do echo $line; echo -e `modinfo $line -n`\\n; done;
```

will output a list of the kernel modules, along with its file path.

Comment: But `modinfo` doesn't help if the module was loaded with an alternate name with `modprobe -o` or if the module file was renamed.

Comment: @Gilles True, +1

Comment: @Gilles And that exactly is the situation here, so after testing what @BloodPhilia suggested we're still without an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/modules
```

gives you the list (detailed) of the loaded modules (RedHat, Ubuntu, I guess it works for CentOS from which Redhat is based).

Comment: @ring0: That is indeed a simple way to find modules classified by the name under which they were loaded. But it doesn't help if the load name does not match the file name due to the use of `modprobe -o`.

Answer (score -3):

*cat /proc/modules* 
*more /proc/modules* 

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFAPI.png)
*sudo rmmod print*